Isabelle record update reordering
record r =
  a :: nat
  b :: nat
  c :: nat

lemma "P (r ⦇ a := 2, b := 3 ⦈) ⟹ P (r ⦇b := 3, a := 2⦈)"
  apply auto ― ‹doesn't work›
  by (metis r.simps(5) r.simps(6) r.surjective)

Why doesn't auto work, and I have to invoke sledgehammer to do such a simple proof? Shouldn't Isabelle be able to figure out that if the update fields are different, they commute?
Is there a way to teach Isabelle that?

The standard “heuristic” is that you can often increase the reach of automatic methods for records (and product datatypes, too) by injecting a cases or induct invocation. This also works in this instance:
lemma ‹P (rec ⦇ a := 2, b := 3 ⦈) ⟹ P (rec ⦇ b := 3, a := 2 ⦈)›
  apply (cases rec)
  (* ⋀a b c more.
       P (rec⦇ a := 2, b := 3 ⦈) ⟹
       rec = ⦇ a = a, b = b, c = c, … = more ⦈ ⟹ P (rec⦇ b := 3, a := 2 ⦈)
  *)
  by simp

This sure seems counter-intuitive from a mathematical perspective—because in paper proofs one does usually not point out that a certain construction has only one case.
In Isabelle/HOL, it often helps to explicitly add the equation for the constructor pattern, which is achieved through cases my_var.
It might seem even more counter-intuitive to write induct rec here— clearly the datatype is not recursive.
But the proof method induct works just as well and tends to work slightly more often than just cases as the constructor pattern is directly unfolded in the proof state.
Commutativity of updates
Generally, Isabelle of course knows about commutativity of updates.
For all functions there's a generic lemma:
Fun.fun_upd_twist:
  ‹a ≠ c ⟹ (m(a := b))(c := d) = (m(c := d))(a := b)›

For record types, however, things are more complicated.
Technically, they are defined as syntactic and semantic sugar over tuples, which again derive from pairs.
Each record type has its own unrelated type, and each field has its “personal” update function.
So, one would need to introduce the commutativity of updates for every single permutation of updates.
One can.
The simplifier also knows how to prove this in milliseconds:
lemma r_a_b_commute:
  ‹rec ⦇ a := a', b := b' ⦈ = rec ⦇ b := b', a := a' ⦈›
  by simp

With this, the original proof goal of the question becomes immediate:
lemma ‹P (rec ⦇ a := 2, b := 3 ⦈) ⟹ P (rec ⦇ b := 3, a := 2 ⦈)›
  unfolding r_a_b_commute .

Teaching Isabelle/HOL about update commutativity?
Why is r_a_b_commute no standard fact, directly established for a new record type?
I presume that there just would quickly be too many facts that are almost never used.
So, one must tell Isabelle/HOL directly about the instances where it matters.
(You can also use subgoal_tac in apply-style proofs or proof steps in Isar proofs for that.)
That this ad-hoc “teaching” is possible, relies on the Isabelle developers indeed having set up a lot of machinery in the simplifier to deal with records in proofs.
Feel free to browse HOL/Tools/records.ML, where the simprocs are defined, which enable the by simp steps above.
Thanks to that, the simplifier implicitly knows about all the commutativities; it might just not be sufficiently clever to use this knowledge directly.
General warning about records
In my introductory courses on Isabelle, I often see math and CS students using records and tuples a lot because this is close to textbook presentation.
Usually, their lives become a lot easier once I convince them to just use plain functions, locales, and datatype definitions where appropriate. (datatype can also define record-like selection functions.)
Tuples and records in Isabelle just are plagued by technicalities that are necessary to create their superficial convenience.
But in my experience, the technicalities make your life more miserable.
If you can do without records, sledgehammer and auto will get a lot more things done.
So, my general advice is to use record as little as possible.
